# Convert values from a dictionary to a matrix

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix, nested-lists

I have counted the number of times a word appears in a text document and put those values in a dictionary. Now I want to add those amounts to a matrix consisting of the textfiles as columns and the different words as rows.
This is the output of the dictionary:

```
{'test1.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1, 'moes': 1}, 
'test2.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1}, 
'test3.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 2}, 
'test4.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 1, 'ananas': 1}}
```

And the output of the matrix has to look like this:

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'],
['moes', 1, 0, 2, 1],
['appel', 1, 1, 0, 0],
['peer', 1, 1, 1, 1],
['ananas', 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

This is the code I have now to print the matrix, but the number of times a word appears in each document is not implemented yet.

```
term_freq_matrix = []

list_of_files.insert(0," ")
term_freq_matrix.insert(1, list_of_files)

for unique_word in unique_words:
    unique_word = unique_word.split()
    term_freq_matrix.append(unique_word)

print(term_freq_matrix)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without external libraries:

**Code:**

```
d = {'test1.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1, 'moes': 1}, 
    'test2.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1}, 
    'test3.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 2}, 
    'test4.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 1, 'ananas': 1}}

res = [[''] + list(d.keys())]
for c in set(k for v in d.values() for k in v.keys()):
    res.append([c] + [d[k].get(c, 0) for k in res[0][1:]])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'],
 ['peer', 1, 1, 1, 1],
 ['ananas', 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ['appel', 1, 1, 0, 0],
 ['moes', 1, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0)  #d is your dictionary
result = [[''] + df.columns.to_numpy().tolist()]+ df.reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'],
 ['ananas', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
 ['appel', 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 ['moes', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0], 
 ['peer', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
your_dict = {'test1.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1, 'moes': 1}, 
'test2.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1}, 
'test3.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 2}, 
'test4.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 1, 'ananas': 1}}
```

sklearn has a neat utility class for this kind of preprocessing

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(your_dict.values()))
```

The mapping of dictionary key to matrix index is available at `vectorizer.vocabulary_`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
data = {'test1.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1, 'moes': 1}, 'test2.txt': {'peer': 1, 'appel': 1}, 'test3.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 2}, 'test4.txt': {'peer': 1, 'moes': 1, 'ananas': 1}}
h, v = data.keys(), {i for b in data.values() for i in b}
r = [['', *h], *[[b, *[data[k].get(b, 0) for k in h]] for b in v]]
```

Output:

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 
 ['moes', 1, 0, 2, 1], 
 ['peer', 1, 1, 1, 1], 
 ['appel', 1, 1, 0, 0], 
 ['ananas', 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```